# Validação de entrada de dados permitindo TAG HTML

Tags: php, javascript

Preciso fazer uma validação, sempre valido no lado do cliente/JS e servidor/PHP, e permitir que o usuário digite algumas TAGs para formatação do resultado final, alguma dica de como fazer isto? Melhor usar um campo do tipo `textarea` ou usar um editor?

Algumas TAGs que quero permitir:

```
h1 a h6
<p>
<u>
<strong>
<address>
<strong>
```

Answer (score 4):

você pode utilizar desta função nativa do php `strip_tags($texto, $tags_permitidas);`
por exemplo:

```
strip_tags("<strong><span class='block'>texto a ser filtrado</span></strong>", '<strong>');
```

desta forma o resultado seria:

```
<strong>texto a ser filtrado</strong>
```

para maiores informações veja a documentação:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 2):

Criei a função abaixo para salvar os dados do usuário, fiz alguns testes e consegui executar o filtro e salvar com sucesso.

```
function fDescribe() { 
        functions::startSession();
        if($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token']) {
            $this->describeC = strip_tags($_POST['textarea'],
             '<h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><p><u><strong><em><address><strong><br><abbr>');

            $this->conn = parent::getCon();                                 
            $this->pQuery = $this->conn->prepare("update table set description=? where user_id=? limit 1"); 
            $this->pQuery->bindParam(1, $this->describeC);
            $this->pQuery->bindParam(2, $_SESSION['id']);
            $this->result = $this->pQuery->execute();
            unset($this->conn); 
            if($this->result == true) {
                functions::generateJsonMsg('success', null, null, null, null);
                exit();
            } else  {
                functions::generateJsonMsg('fault', 'queryFault', null, null, null);
                exit();
            }                               
    } else 
        return false;   
}
```